# Polymer 1.0 behaviors changes not propagated

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to make my custom i18n behaviors (there is no i18n component that fit my need currently, i check i18n-msg, i18n-next some custom implementations found on stackoverflow...).

It works well on the first page generation but when i try to change my language, labels are not updated.

Here my code :

Behavior :

```
var Polymer = Polymer || {};
    /* Defining behavior's */
    Polymer.I18n = Polymer.I18n ||{
        properties: {
            lang: {
                type: String,
                value: "en",
                observer: '_onChangedLocale'
            },
            /** Exposes all translations */
            translation: {
                type: Object,
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            /* Initialisation */
            this._onChangedLocale(Polymer.I18n.lang);
        },
        _onChangedLocale: function(locale) {
            switch(locale) {
                case 'de':
                    Polymer.I18n.translation = i18nDE;
                    break;
                default:
                    Polymer.I18n.translation = i18nEN;
            }
        },
        i18n: function(key) {
            return Polymer.I18n.translation[key] ? Polymer.I18n.translation[key] : key;
        }
}
```

Component that implement the behavior :

```
<dom-module id="my-page">
    <template>
        [[i18n('hello')]]
        <span on-click="onChangeLanguageDEClick">DE</span>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "my-page",
            /* use localisation */
            behaviors: [Polymer.I18n],
            onChangeLanguageDEClick:function (event, detail, sender){
                this.lang = 'de';
            },
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

i18nDE et i18nEN are JsonObject that contains translations.

When i click on 'DE', _onChangedLocale is called, Polymer.I18n.translation is updated but NOT the '[[i18n('hello')]]' which stay with his first value like if nothing happened.

Did I miss something ? The polymer doc speak about 'notifyPath' but I don't understand how to use it in my case

RESOLUTION :
The problem was the lifecycle. 
Polymer evaluate dom and data-binding before component properties  initialization... Either you got error that say that your properties is not defined (in case you are not using 'created' callback) when you are using this.my-prop. Or like i did, it works only the first time but change will never be repercuted.

It's absolutely not documented and don't see other informations about it but to get rid of that, i give a second parameter to my [[i18n('hello')]] => [[i18n('hello',translation)]]. The function i18n still take only on argument but doing that, you tell polymer that the function use a propertie 'translation' that allow him to CHANGE the lifecycle and evaluate the expression AFTER the properties initialization. And now it works as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it was my first try (based on https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html) and it does not work neither.

I isolate the problem (it's not polymer behavior relative) :

Look this minimalist code of my i18n component :

```
<dom-module id="my-page">
<template>
    [[expr('toto',word)]]
    <span on-click="onClickButton">Change plz</span>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-page",
        /* use localisation */
        properties : {
            word: {
                type: Object,
            }
        },
        ready: function() {
            this.onChange('Try it');
        },
        onClickButton:function (event, detail, sender, arg){
            this.onChange('CHANGED !');
        },
        onChange:function (arg){
            var  json = {};
            json.toto = arg;
            this.word = json;
        },
        expr:function(arg) {
            return this.word[arg];
        }
    });
</script>
```

This code works (when i click on 'change plz', the binding is updated as expected)  but I don't understand why because i made an error on this line :
[[expr('toto',word)]].

My function 'expr' does not take a second argument and guess what. If I remove it like that [[expr('toto')]], it does not work anymore (Cannot read property 'toto' of undefined) !! oO

Someone can explain me this behavior then I would be able to extend it to my i18n component ?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend to have your own namespace and not to use Polymer. 
Add import to polymer.html in your behavior definition if it does not exist now.

Try making below changes and see if it works.

```
    /* Defining behavior's */
    Polymer.I18n = Polymer.I18n ||{
        properties: {
            lang: {
                type: String,
                value: "en",
                observer: '_onChangedLocale'
            },
            /** Exposes all translations */
            translation: {
                type: Object,
            }
        },
        created: function() {
            /* Initialisation */
            this._onChangedLocale(this.lang);
        },
        _onChangedLocale: function(locale) {
            switch(locale) {
                case 'de':
                    this.translation = i18nDE;
                    break;
                default:
                    this.translation = i18nEN;
            }
        },
        i18n: function(key) {
            return this.translation[key] ? this.translation[key] : key;
        }
```